# How to solve the site <title> tag being displayed twice?

Tags: title, wp-title

My [website](https://crackisb.in/gmat-coaching-in-hyderabad/) theme `header.php` uses this code:

```php
<title><?php wp_title('&lsaquo;', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

And I'm seeing two `<title>` tags in the page source.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the two `<title>` tags most likely because your theme has the [`title-tag` support](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/) which automatically adds the title tags in the document `head`.

Excerpt from the above linked page on Make WordPress Core:

> #### Adding titles to themes
>
> Starting with 4.1 and [Twenty
> Fifteen](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/30097), the
> recommended way for themes to display titles is by adding theme
> support like this:
>
> ```
> function theme_slug_setup() {
>   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
> }
> add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
> ```
>
> Support should be added on the `after_setup_theme` or `init` action,
> but no later than that. It does not accept any further arguments.
>
> By declaring support like this, **themes acknowledge that they are not
> defining titles on their own** and WordPress can add it safely without
> duplication.

So if the theme does support the automatic `<title>` tag (try looking for `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )` in the theme's `functions.php` file), then don't manually put the title tags in the `header.php` template.

And if you actually wanted to customize the title or the positioning of the title parts, then you can use the [`document_title_parts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) or if you're using any SEO plugin, then you might be able to adjust the title parts without using any custom code; however, please consult the plugin support documentation/site/forums for assistance in adjusting that parts or customizing the site title. :)